# Looping through files and protect worksheet by opening and saving one at a time

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on more than 200 excel files and I need to protect my excel worksheets before using it to send to other companies. The code below managed to work but the problem is it keeps opening all the excel files in the folder until it ran out of memory to process and I also have to manually save all the files that are opened

Is there a way where the code can loop the excel files in the folder one at a time and save it before proceeding with the next excel file ?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    FolderName = "C:\Users\Desktop\PROJECTS\PROJECT FILE\A"
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
    Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xlsx")

    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)

        With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)

           ' here comes the code for the operations on every file the code finds

        ActiveSheet.Protect "password", True, True


        End With

        ' go to the next file in the folder
        Fname = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    FolderName = "C:\Users\Desktop\PROJECTS\PROJECT FILE\A"
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
    Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xlsx")

    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)

        With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)

           ' here comes the code for the operations on every file the code finds

        ActiveSheet.Protect "password", True, True
        .save
        .close

        End With

        ' go to the next file in the folder
        Fname = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```